# Firestore gRPC API Sample Usage in Golang

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, rpc

New to firestore and gRPC in general. I've been trying to figure out how to interact with the Firestore RPC API from golang. They document the API well [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc), but do not show how to initialize the connections. Some questions I have are,

1. From golang, would I use the grpc package or the builtin rpc.
2. What URL would I use to connect to the API.
3. When connnecting to a cloud based RPC API like this, do I need to have the .proto files locally to be able to interact with it?
4. How to authenticate with a users firebase ID token.
5. How to create a record authenticated as said user.

Cheers.

Edit: I have been able to connect thanks to Anar. But I can't test anything because Im not really sure how to authenticate or create a record. Any help with an example would be great. Code so far:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("firestore.googleapis.com", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must use google.golang.org/grpc package
2. As documentation you must use `firestore.googleapis.com` to create client stub.

[image]

3.You don't need it proto file locally. you can just create grpc client and use server methods which available here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that answers the original question.  Would you have an example of authenticating with a users idToken and creating a record in firestore?

Comment: I never use firestore service before however, the logic is the same. why you don't try to use Golang firestore package? I look that and it has pretty good documentation which includes examples.

I recommend you read the pkg and examples. 

https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore?tab=doc

Comment: I believe the golang sdk is an admin sdk only, and does not support user level authentication, which is why im stuck using the rpc api. I would love to be proven wrong but I haven't found a way to do it with the firestore pkg.

Comment: Oops, authentication is not part of firestore package. For authentication just use this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#go.

Comment: Not quite what I meant but thanks for the answer. I have already grabbed the users auuthentication id. I want to use that token to process the firestore RPC request AS the user.